# Surface connector and conduits

Tags: revit-api

How can I conect a conduit on a family instance that has a surface connector using API ? I am doing good connecting with "normal" connectors but when the family has only surface connectors, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the normal connection functionality, as demonstrated by the discussions of all the different ways to [create a rolling offset](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/01/final-rolling-offset-using-pipecreate.html). Also check out the [CreateAirHandler SDK sample](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/11/connector-direction-and-createairhandler.html). It creates such a connector, but does not show how to attach to it in the project. Presumably because there is nothing special about it  :-)